# Python Selenium close tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using `Selenium` in my `Python` project, sometimes there is a new tab open(and i want to use this tab and close the first one), I do it with this code:

```
window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(window_before)
driver.close()

time.sleep(2)
```

After that I try to load a new URL with:

```
driver.get(mainUrl)
```

and I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: NoSuchWindowException
Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: You need to switch to new window before next request, so explicitly use `driver.switch_to_window(<NEW_WINDOW>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get back to TAB which is not closed, for instance:

```
window_to_close = driver.window_handles[0]
window_to_keep = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_to_close)
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(window_to_keep)

driver.get(mainUrl)
```